# How do I exclude the lowest level terms in a taxonomy?

Tags: wp-query, custom-taxonomy, taxonomy

I am using `$custom_terms = get_term_children( $term_id, $taxonomy_name );` to display child terms for the current taxonomy term. What I would like to do is exclude the 4th level terms as I don't want to display them and nothing that I have tried so far like `'hide_empty'` and `'parent'` haven't worked for me.

I found this question that is similar to what I am trying to do:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28079153/wp-query-exclude-all-terms-of-a-custom-taxonomy

I do not want to explicitly declare which terms to exclude because there are so many and the client may add more. I need this to be dynamic and not display the 4th level terms for the current taxonomy.

My taxonomies are 4 levels deep:

Level 1 > Level 2 > Level 3 > Level 4

Here is my code so far:

```
$term_id = get_queried_object()->term_id;
$taxonomy_name = 'product_range';
$custom_terms = get_term_children( $term_id, $taxonomy_name );

foreach($custom_terms as $custom_term) {

  $term = get_term_by( 'id', $custom_term, $taxonomy_name );
  wp_reset_query();
  $args = array(
    'post_type' => 'product',
    'posts_per_page' => 1,
    'tax_query' => array(
      array(
        'taxonomy' => 'product_range',
        'field' => 'slug',
        'terms' => $term->slug,
        'parent' => 0
        ),
     ),
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have only 4 level, and each third level term has children, the we can determine the fourth level term if have children:

```
$term_id       = get_queried_object()->term_id;
$taxonomy_name = 'product_range';
$custom_terms  = get_term_children( $term_id, $taxonomy_name );

foreach ( $custom_terms as $custom_term ) {

    $term          = get_term_by( 'id', $custom_term, $taxonomy_name );
    $terms_chilren = get_term_children( $term_id, $taxonomy_name );

    wp_reset_query();

    // if we can not get a term`s children, we can confirm the term is the fourth level term.
    if ( ! empty( $terms_chilren ) && ! is_wp_error( $terms_chilren ) ) {
       $args = [
        'post_type'      => 'product',
        'posts_per_page' => 1,
        'tax_query'      => [
            [
                'taxonomy' => 'product_range',
                'field'    => 'slug',
                'terms'    => $term->slug,
                'parent'   => 0,
            ],
        ],
    ];
  }
}
```